# Java's enum... Where are they created?

Tags: java, c#, enums, heap-memory, stack-memory

Since enum in C# are on the stack, I was wondering where enum, in Java, where created. On the stack? On the heap? In some mysterious other place?

Enumeration in C# are more primitive than those in Java, this might explain why they are created on the stack...

Where are they? I can't find them!

Thanks

Comment: Enums in C# *can* be on the stack, but they can be on the heap too. It all depends where they are used (field/parameter/local variable). They are value types though, maybe that's where the confusion comes from? Besides, in .NET it should not matter where the contents of a variable is stored; this is just an implementation detail (and might change in a different implementation of the CLR).

Comment: Out of wild curiosity, why do you want to know whether they are on the stack or the heap?

Comment: @whaley Simple curiosity

Comment: They're on the heap, just another reason why Java is so  laughably terrible in terms of performance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Enums in Java are also objects: for example, enums can have instance variables/methods/constructors and implement interfaces. All this makes me think they're handled just like other objects by jvm.

Comment: Which means...  They're on the heap.

Answer (score 7):

Since Java enums [extend](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html) `java.lang.Enum`, they are created on the heap like all other Java objects.

Comment: Technically, they do extend `Enum`.  But it's their status as objects (ie: their indirectly extending `Object` as well) that'd make them reference types.

Comment: @0xA3: They extend `java.lang.Enum` which itself extends `java.lang.Object`.

Comment: No, 0xA3, I mean what I said.  Look at the javadocs link I posted.  They extend java.lang.Enum, which in turn extends java.lang.Object.

Answer (score 4):

Enums are objects in Java, so they are on the heap. However, for each type there is only a fixed number of them. **Client code is dealing with references** to these enum objects, so doesn't actually create anything on the heap. As ever from a specification point of view: local variable references are on the stack; object field references are on the heap.

Comment: first sentence - "so they are on the stack" - I think you meant to type "so they are on the heap" ;)

Comment: @serg10 Yes. Didn't want that # either.

Answer (score 2):

They are objects, just like any other object, so the enum itself is on the heap. A variable that holds a reference to an enum may be on the stack if it is a function variable, or it may be on the heap inside some other object if it is a member of an object.